# Limit question multivariable analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation, substitution

Let f be a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as $f(x,y)=(x^2,y^2)$ let T from  $\mathbb{R}^2$ to  $\mathbb{R}^2$ be the map $T(x,y)=(2x,4y)$ then to show that f is differentiable at $(1,2)$ with derivative T, the following change of variables is made:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,2)}\frac{\|f(x,y)-f(1,2)-T((x,y)-(1,2))\|}{\|(x,y)-(1,2)\|}$$

Set $(x,y)=(1,2)+(a,b)$ we have the above expression is equal to

$$\lim_{(a,b) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\|f(1+a,2+b)-f(1,2)-T((a,b)\|}{\|(a,b)\|}$$

The question I have is – why are we allowed to make the substitution?  How can we be sure that the two expressions are equal? Can this be generalized? What lemma or Theorem is involved with regards to this substitution and equality?  I'm trying to understand this at a formal level, rather than on an intuitive one.

Comment: Why should the substitution change the result? a=x-1 and b=y-2. In the limit since x goes to 1, a goes to 1-1=0 and since y goes to 2, goes to 2-2=0. All checks out

Comment: @A. P I understand it at an intuitive level, I'm having difficulty with formalizing it, could you formalize the argument, please?

Comment: Sorry i don't se why this shouldn't be true therefore I don't think I can help you. But heres an attempt: $lim_{a \to 0}f(a)=lim_{ a +1\to 1}f(a+1-1)=lim_{x \to 1}f(x-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}\frac{\left\lVert f(x,y)-f(1,2)-T\bigl((x,y)-(1,2)\bigr)\right\rVert}{\bigl\lVert(x,y)-(1,2)\bigr\rVert}=0$$is equivalent to$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}<\delta\implies\frac{\left\lVert f(x,y)-f(1,2)-T\bigl((x,y)-(1,2)\bigr)\right\rVert}{\bigl\lVert(x,y)-(1,2)\bigr\rVert}<\varepsilon.\tag1$$And asserting that$$\lim_{(a,b)\to(0,0)}\frac{\bigl\lVert f(1+a,2+b)-f(1,2)-T(a,b)\bigr\rvert}{\bigl\lVert(a,b)\bigr\rVert}=0$$is equivalent to$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):\sqrt{a^2+b^2}<\delta\implies\frac{\left\lVert f(1+a,2+b)-f(1,2)-T(a,b)\right\rVert}{\bigl\lVert(a,b)\bigr\rVert}<\varepsilon.\tag2$$It is clear that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent: for each $\varepsilon>0$, any $\delta$ that works for $(1)$ also works for $(2)$ and vice-versa.

Comment: When does the change of variable/substitution trick work? What conditions must it satisfy?

Comment: It will work for any bijective continuous map from $\mathbb R^2$ into itself. In your case, that bijective continuous map is $(a,b)\mapsto(1+a,2+b)$.